# Implementing 3 level Expandable ListView android?

Tags: android

I am having a navigation drawer and trying to implement an expandable LisView in android having 3 levels in it:

Trending

Looks

Men

--Clothing
-------Western wear

-------casuals

--Footwear

-------Boots

-------Flip flops

Women

--Clothing

-------Western wear

-------casuals

--Footwear

-------Boots

-------Flip flop

I am taking an expandable ListView1 and setting another expandable ListView2 as its child which will expand the 3rd level sub categories.
But i am failing to get the desired result.
2nd level categories are not coming so the 3rd level is unreachable . 
Any idea  or help would be appreciated .I fail to get a solution anywhere.

`public void prepareListData() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        listDataHeader=new ArrayList();
        listDataChild=new HashMap>();

```
    listDataHeader.add("Trending");
    listDataHeader.add("Looks");
    listDataHeader.add("Men");
    listDataHeader.add("Women");
    listDataHeader.add("Leaderboard");
    List<String> Men=new ArrayList<>();
    Men.add("Clothing");
    Men.add("Footwear");
    Men.add("Accesories");

    List<String> Women=new ArrayList<>();
    Women.add("Western wear");
    Women.add("Footwear");
    Women.add("Ethnic wear");
    Women.add("Lingerie");
    Women.add("Accesories");

    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2),Men); // Header, Child data
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(3),Women);

    //Men sub sub categories

    //listDataSubChildHeader.add("Clothing");
    //listDataSubChildHeader.add("Clothing");

    List<String> menClothing=new ArrayList<>();
    menClothing.add("Casuals");
    menClothing.add("Ethnic wear");

    List<String> menFootwear=new ArrayList<>();
    menFootwear.add("Boots");
    menFootwear.add("Casual Shoes");

    List<String> menAccesories=new ArrayList<>();
    menAccesories.add("Bags and wallets");
    menAccesories.add("Caps and hats");

    //sub sub categories
            //listDataSubChildHeader=new ArrayList<String>();
    menListDataSubChild=new HashMap<String,List<String>>();
    womenListDataSubChild=new HashMap<String,List<String>>();

    menListDataSubChild.put("Clothing",menClothing);//0
    menListDataSubChild.put("Footwear", menFootwear);//1
    menListDataSubChild.put("Accesories", menAccesories);//2

    //Women sub sub categories
    List<String> WomenWestern=new ArrayList<>();
    menClothing.add("Bottom Wear");
    menClothing.add("Dresses");

    List<String> WomenFootwear=new ArrayList<>();
    menFootwear.add("Bellies and Loafers");
    menFootwear.add("Foots");

    List<String> WomenEthnic=new ArrayList<>();
    menAccesories.add("Kurtas and Kurtis");
    menAccesories.add("Leggings");

    List<String> WomenAccesories=new ArrayList<>();
    menAccesories.add("Bags and wallets");
    menAccesories.add("Belts");

    List<String> WomenLingerie=new ArrayList<>();
    menAccesories.add("Night wear");
    menAccesories.add("Swim wear");

    womenListDataSubChild.put("Western wear",WomenWestern);//0
    womenListDataSubChild.put("Footwear",WomenFootwear);//1
    womenListDataSubChild.put("Ethnic wear",WomenEthnic);//2
    womenListDataSubChild.put("Lingerie",WomenLingerie);//3
    womenListDataSubChild.put("Accesories",WomenAccesories);//4





}`
```

`public void expandableListAdapter() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //listAdapter instance
        listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), listDataHeader, listDataChild,menListDataSubChild,womenListDataSubChild);
        // Set the adapter for the leftMenu list view

```
    expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    //Calling fuction for adding icon for Navigation Bar
    addingNavIconOnActionBar();

    // Listview Group click listener
    expListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, long id) {
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
             //"Group Clicked " + listDataHeader.get(groupPosition),
             //Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if(groupPosition==0)
            {
                Intent trendingIntent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Trending.class);
                startActivity(trendingIntent);
            }
            else if(groupPosition==1)
            {
                Intent trendingIntent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Looks.class);
                startActivity(trendingIntent);

            }

            return false;
        }
    });

 // Listview Group expanded listener
    expListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Expanded",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

 // Listview Group collasped listener
    expListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new OnGroupCollapseListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Collapsed",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });


//  mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
    // Listview on child click listener
    expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)
                            + " : "
                            + listDataChild.get(
                                       listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(
                                    childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();`enter code here`
            return false;
        }
    });
}` 

enter code here
```

public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

```
private Context _context;
List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
// child data in format of header title, child title
HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

//sub sub category of men and women
private HashMap<String, List<String>> _menListDatasubChild,_womenListDatasubChild;

ExpandableListView expChildList;
ChildExpandableListAdapter childAdapter;
public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context,
        List<String> listDataHeader,
        HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild, HashMap<String, List<String>> menListDataSubChild, HashMap<String, List<String>> womenListDataSubChild) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this._context=context;
    this._listDataChild=listDataChild;
    this._listDataHeader=listDataHeader;
    this._menListDatasubChild=menListDataSubChild;
    this._womenListDatasubChild=womenListDataSubChild;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .get(childPosititon);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }

   // TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
     //      .findViewById(R.id.ListHeader1);

    //calling sub level Adapter

    Log.e("groupPos", String.valueOf(groupPosition));
    Log.e("childText", childText);
    expChildList=(ExpandableListView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.expChildList);

    childAdapter=new ChildExpandableListAdapter(this._context,groupPosition);
    expChildList.setAdapter(childAdapter);
 // Listview Group click listener
    expChildList.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, long id) {
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
             //"Group Clicked " + listDataHeader.get(groupPosition),
             //Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            return false;
        }
    });

 // Listview Group expanded listener
    expChildList.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {

        }
    });

 // Listview Group collasped listener
    expChildList.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new OnGroupCollapseListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {


        }
    });


//  mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
    // Listview on child click listener
    expChildList.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            return false;
        }
    });
    //txtListChild.setText(childText);
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {

    if(groupPosition==0)
        return 0;
    else if(groupPosition==1)
        return 0;
    else if(groupPosition==4)
        return 0;
    else
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this._listDataHeader.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@SuppressLint("InflateParams")
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group,null);
    }

    TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
           .findViewById(R.id.ListHeader);

    lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);
    ImageView iconExpand = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon_expand);
    ImageView iconCollapse = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon_collapse);

    if(getChildrenCount(groupPosition)==0)
    {
    iconExpand.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    iconCollapse.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
else if(isExpanded)
{
    iconExpand.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    iconCollapse.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
else
{
    iconExpand.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    iconCollapse.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}


//********sub sub child adapter

public class ChildExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {


    Context context;
    int _groupPosition;
    public ChildExpandableListAdapter(
            Context context, int groupPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.context=context;

        this._groupPosition=groupPosition;

        Log.e("gP",""+_groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(_groupPosition==2)//men sub category
        {
            if(groupPosition==0)
                return "Clothing";
            else if(groupPosition==1)
                return "Footwear";
            else
                return "Accesories";
        }
        else if(_groupPosition==3)//female sub category
        {
            if(groupPosition==0)
                return "Western wear";
            else if(groupPosition==1)
                return "Footwear";
            else if(groupPosition==2)
                return "Ethnic wear";
            else if(groupPosition==2)
                return "Lingerie";
            else
                return "Accesories";

        }

        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //return this.__listDataChild.get(groupPosition)
        if(_groupPosition==2)
        {
            return _menListDatasubChild.get(getGroup(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
        }
        else if(_groupPosition==3)
        {
            return _womenListDatasubChild.get(getGroup(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String headerTitle =(String)getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group1,null);
        }

        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
               .findViewById(R.id.ListHeader1);
        Log.e("HeaderTitle",headerTitle);
        lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

        return convertView;     
       }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.sub_explist_row, null);
        }

        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
               .findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        txtListChild.setText(childText);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }



enter code here




}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Note: You should not combine any scrollable widgets (like `ListView` inside another `ListView`).

`ExpandableListView` is designed to handle two layers not more, don't try it, it will make your life hell.

**Option 1:**

Search for something like `TreeView`. This will allow you to have more than 2 expandable layers.

**Option 2:**

Keep the structure simple because there's just not enough room on the phone screen. Have only one or two levels always expanded in the drawer. You can use plain old `ListView` with custom adapter handling multiple view types. Move the rest to main content.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an Tree View for this.
Here's a short guide how we did it:

- Create a Tree View and let it use an internal ListView as single child.
- Create a TreeObject class, that stores the expanded state and has references to parents and children.
- on each click on the listview update the state of the clicked treeobject and filter the list contents to only contain the "visible" elements.
- implement the ListViewAdapter to handle this, and write a getView() method that shows the handles, and does the necessary indentation.

Answer (score 0):

Use This Code and add category which you want to Enter

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
HelperDatabaseAdapterClass helperDatabaseAdapterClass;

private ArrayList<Product>pProductArrayList=new ArrayList<Product>();;
private ArrayList<SubCategory>pSubItemArrayList=new ArrayList<SubCategory>();;
private ArrayList<SubCategory>pSubItemArrayList2=new ArrayList<SubCategory>();;
private LinearLayout mLinearListView;
boolean isFirstViewClick=false;
boolean isSecondViewClick=false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    helperDatabaseAdapterClass=new HelperDatabaseAdapterClass(this);
    mLinearListView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_listview);

    /**
     *
     */
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> Colormap = HelperDatabaseAdapterClass.find("select * from Color", null);
    int colorcount = 0;
    ArrayList<ItemList> mItemListArray=new ArrayList<ItemList>();
    for (int i = 0; i < Colormap.size(); i++) {

        mItemListArray.add(new ItemList(Colormap.get(i).get("Name"), Colormap.get(i).get("Quantity")));
        colorcount = colorcount+Integer.parseInt(Colormap.get(i).get("Quantity"));
    }
    pSubItemArrayList.add(new SubCategory("Color", colorcount+"", mItemListArray));


    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> Clothsmap = HelperDatabaseAdapterClass.find("select * from Cloths", null);

    int cohcount= 0;
    ArrayList<ItemList> mItemListArray2=new ArrayList<ItemList>();
    for (int i = 0; i < Clothsmap.size(); i++) {
        mItemListArray2.add(new ItemList(Clothsmap.get(i).get("Name"), Clothsmap.get(i).get("Quantity")));
        cohcount = cohcount+Integer.parseInt(Clothsmap.get(i).get("Quantity"));

    }

    pSubItemArrayList2.add(new SubCategory("Cloths", cohcount+"", mItemListArray2));

    pProductArrayList.add(new Product("Emotions", colorcount+"", pSubItemArrayList));
    pProductArrayList.add(new Product("Garments", cohcount+"", pSubItemArrayList2));


    /***
     * adding item into listview
     */
    for (int i = 0; i < pProductArrayList.size(); i++) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = null;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View mLinearView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_first, null);

        final TextView mProductName = (TextView) mLinearView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
        final RelativeLayout mLinearFirstArrow=(RelativeLayout)mLinearView.findViewById(R.id.linearFirst);
        final ImageView mImageArrowFirst=(ImageView)mLinearView.findViewById(R.id.imageFirstArrow);
        final LinearLayout mLinearScrollSecond=(LinearLayout)mLinearView.findViewById(R.id.linear_scroll);

        if(isFirstViewClick==false){
            mLinearScrollSecond.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mImageArrowFirst.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arw_lt);
        }
        else{
            mLinearScrollSecond.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mImageArrowFirst.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arw_down);
        }

        mLinearFirstArrow.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                if(isFirstViewClick==false){
                    isFirstViewClick=true;
                    mImageArrowFirst.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arw_down);
                    mLinearScrollSecond.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }else{
                    isFirstViewClick=false;
                    mImageArrowFirst.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arw_lt);
                    mLinearScrollSecond.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });


        final String name = pProductArrayList.get(i).getpName();
        mProductName.setText(name+"   "+pProductArrayList.get(i).getpCount());

        /**
         *
         */
        for (int j = 0; j < pProductArrayList.get(i).getmSubCategoryList().size(); j++) {

            LayoutInflater inflater2 = null;
            inflater2 = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View mLinearView2 = inflater2.inflate(R.layout.row_second, null);

            TextView mSubItemName = (TextView) mLinearView2.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);
            final RelativeLayout mLinearSecondArrow=(RelativeLayout)mLinearView2.findViewById(R.id.linearSecond);
            final ImageView mImageArrowSecond=(ImageView)mLinearView2.findViewById(R.id.imageSecondArrow);
            final LinearLayout mLinearScrollThird=(LinearLayout)mLinearView2.findViewById(R.id.linear_scroll_third);

            if(isSecondViewClick==false){
                mLinearScrollThird.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mImageArrowSecond.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arw_lt);
            }
            else{
                mLinearScrollThird.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mImageArrowSecond.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arw_down);
            }

            mLinearSecondArrow.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                    if(isSecondViewClick==false){
                        isSecondViewClick=true;
                        mImageArrowSecond.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arw_down);
                        mLinearScrollThird.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    }else{
                        isSecondViewClick=false;
                        mImageArrowSecond.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arw_lt);
                        mLinearScrollThird.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });


            final String catName = pProductArrayList.get(i).getmSubCategoryList().get(j).getpSubCatName();
            final String catCount = pProductArrayList.get(i).getmSubCategoryList().get(j).getpSubCatCount();
            mSubItemName.setText(catName+"     "+catCount);


            /**
             *
             */
            for (int k = 0; k < pProductArrayList.get(i).getmSubCategoryList().get(j).getmItemListArray().size(); k++) {

                LayoutInflater inflater3 = null;
                inflater3 = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View mLinearView3 = inflater3.inflate(R.layout.row_third, null);

                TextView mItemName = (TextView) mLinearView3.findViewById(R.id.textViewItemName);
                TextView mItemPrice = (TextView) mLinearView3.findViewById(R.id.textViewItemPrice);
                final String itemName = pProductArrayList.get(i).getmSubCategoryList().get(j).getmItemListArray().get(k).getItemName();
                final String itemPrice = pProductArrayList.get(i).getmSubCategoryList().get(j).getmItemListArray().get(k).getItemPrice();
                mItemName.setText(itemName);
                mItemPrice.setText(itemPrice);

                mLinearScrollThird.addView(mLinearView3);
            }

            mLinearScrollSecond.addView(mLinearView2);

        }

        mLinearListView.addView(mLinearView);
    }
}

public void Insert(View v) {
    Intent i =new Intent(getApplicationContext(), InsertData.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

}